# What does "Gestalt" do?

Tags: c, macos, unix

On Mac OS X, what does the function gestalt do? What is it used for? Could you please give a brief example? I know that it has something to do with system calls, but what exactly?

Comment: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?DeterminingOSVersion

Comment: This name has a long history in old Mac OS: http://tinyurl.com/6dyah7m (had to use tinyurl since SO mangled the paren in the title)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Gestalt gives you details about the system the application is running on, such as the OS version. Here is a simple example to get the Mac OSX version on the system this binary is run:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Gestalt.h>

int main() {
    SInt32 versMaj, versMin, versBugFix;
    Gestalt(gestaltSystemVersionMajor, &versMaj);
    Gestalt(gestaltSystemVersionMinor, &versMin);
    Gestalt(gestaltSystemVersionBugFix, &versBugFix);

    printf("Mac Version: %d.%d.%d\n", versMaj, versMin, versBugFix);
}
```

compile and run this test with:

```
gcc -framework Carbon test.c && ./a.out
```

You may aslo need a flag like `-I/Developer/Headers/FlatCarbon/`

This should give a response like: `Mac Version: 10.6.8`

I created this example after reading the [official docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/Gestalt_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000036-CH5g-149900).